# chai-http request throwing ssl error for https request

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test a simple nodejs https request with Mocha , chai.

**Test.js**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let server = require('../../server');
const fs = require('fs');

const key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key.pem');
const cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key-cert.pem');

  describe('/GET test route', () => {
  it('it should GET test route', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get('/service/test')
        .key(key)
        .cert(cert)
        .end((err, res) => {
              console.log('Testtttttttttt   ', res);
              res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
  });
});
```

This is throwing the error below :

```
{ Error: write EPROTO 140735569253248:error:1408F10B:SSL 

routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:

    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:836:14)
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write',
  response: undefined }
```

I have tried setting below as mentioned [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/370) :

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

But it is not working. Is there any way to disable strict ssl for the tests ? or any help regarding this will be very helpful.

Comment: same problem, did you find a fix?